# Permission denied for require, when trying to run script via exec

Tags: php, permission-denied

When I try to run a php script, from another php script, with the `exec` command, I am getting a permission denied error for one of the files required by the script.

The strange thing is, that if I run the same script from the terminal, the permission denied error does not appear.

This is my script:

```
<?php

require('/path/to/folder1/config.php');
require('/path/to/folder2/autoload.php');

$Daemon = new Daemon_StorageVirtualTransactionCalculator();
```

The two required files are in two different folders in the file system, both of the folders every folder above and below them, and every file INSIDE the folders are set currently to 777 permission. The first require fires without an error, but on the second fire request I get the following error message:

> Warning: require(/path/to/folder1/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /original/script/folder/storageTransactionVirtual.php on line 10

I can't figure out what's causing this error, it definitely shouldn't be a permission problem, like the error states, as everything is currently set to 777 permission.

Comment: Have you checked the ownership on the files?

Comment: Files are owned by `root`. I am fairly new to linux, but doesn't the 777 permission, disregard ownerships totally?

Comment: Nope, ownerships and file permissions are different, the owner are the people allowed to execute the file

Comment: Okay, what should I change the owner to? I tried with my personal account, but still permission denied error.

Comment: The executioner of the php (usually apache or www-data)

Comment: Still getting the errors, and the other folder, which requires correctly, is also owned by root. Php has no problem there...

Comment: an ideal set up is: files -> 755 and folders -> 644. Everything owned by the php execution user (think can be found in .ini) - but aside from that, I can't recommend much more without being on your server

Comment: The strange thing is, that when I run the file from a terminal, I don't get this permission error. I can't understand why though...

Comment: Because PHP user != terminal user